# Problems with Eclipse and m2eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, m2eclipse

To use the latest version of the hibernate (version 3.6.1)  , I refer to this the  [guide](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users) to add the  [Jboss repository URL](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/) to my project POM file. Then I go to the `Maven Repositories View` to  rebuild the index for this repository .

After the rebuild , I still cannot search  hibernate core version 3.6.1 when adding the dependencies using the m2eclipse 's POM GUI editor , and also cannot find  hibernate-core  3.6.1 in the `org.hibernate` node  when browsing the repository tree  of the added  Jboss repository  using the `Maven Repositories View` .  However ,  I can find the 3.6.1 version  when I browse the added  Jboss repository using the browser directly (which is at https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/)

Why the contents of the repository tree in m2eclipse is different from that using the browser?
What happen here and how to make  m2eclipse  also get the 3.6.1 version ?

Here is repository setting added in my pom.xml

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.jboss.org</id>
            <name>JBoss Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
 </repositories>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot I see `repo1.maven.org`, but you'll need `https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/`. I also have 3.6.1-Final of Hibernate in my project using m2eclipse, and there is no problem fetching it. Please check your `pom.xml` if you have defined a `<repository>` which points to the jboss repo.

Please paste the source of your `pom.xml`, it seems that there is an error if you can not get it.

Comment: Hi Tim , those screenshots are for the question 2 , they are not my setting . To avoid confusion , I open a new question for that problem. I pasted back my pom.xml , which originally points to `http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss` . I have tried to change to your suggested URL , rebuild the index , and still cannot fetch 3.6.1-Final of Hibernate . The latest version I can see in the repository  tree is 3.6.0.CR2

Comment: Can you give me the link to the new question? But browsing with a browser into `https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/` there is the 3.6.1-Final version. So, very strange, it seems it fetchs not from this repository, or is not upated correctly.